# Return xml file from spring MVC controller

Tags: java, xml, spring, file, spring-mvc

I have tried a lot to return a file from the controller function.

This is my function:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody public FileSystemResource getFile() {
     return new FileSystemResource(new File("try.txt")); 
}
```

I got this error message:

> Could not write JSON:
>   No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
>   (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
>   (through reference chain:
>   org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource[\"outputStream\"]->java.io.FileOutputStream[\"fd\"]);
>   nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
>   (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
>   (through reference chain: org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource[\"outputStream\"]->java.io.FileOutputStream[\"fd\"])

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

And, how should I send from the client (JavaScript, jQuery)?

Comment: What `HttpMessageConverter` instances have you registered?

Comment: ammm..., I am new to Spring. Can you explain me?

Comment: I want to see your MVC configuration.

Comment: Also tell us which request headers your client sends.

Comment: On the client I used the simple the jQuery get: `jQuery.get("http://localhost:8086/vos-api/StreamProcessingDiagrams/v1/setting/createFOO",  function( data ) {  jQuery( ".result" ).html( data ); });`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT 2: First of all - see edit 1 in the bottom - that't the right way to do it. However, if you can't get your serializer to work, you can use this solution, where you read the XML file into a string, and promts the user to save it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void saveTxtFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    String yourXmlFileInAString;
    response.setContentType("application/xml");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=thisIsTheFileName.xml");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(YourFile.xml)));
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while((line=br.readLine())!= null){
        sb.append(line);
    }

    yourXmlFileInAString  = sb.toString();

    ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outStream.println(yourXmlFileInAString);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
}
```

That should do the job. Remember, however, that the browser caches URL contents - so it might be a good idea to use a unique URL per file.

EDIT:

After further examination, you should also just be able to add the following piece of code to your Action, to make it work:

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
```

(Or for XML)

```
response.setContentType("application/xml");
```

So your complete solution should be:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody public FileSystemResource getFile(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("application/xml");
    return new FileSystemResource(new File("try.xml")); //Or path to your file 
}
```

Comment: That's not how I read the question. I think everybody knows that a ResponseBody in spring returns an XML/JSON body; but OP asks how to return a file. I give an example of that, and I think it's a bit unjustified that you give me minus for that. You should provide a solution for him instead.

Comment: _I think everybody knows that a ResponseBody in spring returns an XML/JSON body_ It can provide much more than that.

Comment: I really think that you should provide a solution yourself. However - I think my answer to the question "How do you return a file in Spring MVC" is answered with a nifty piece of code - and I hope OP can use it.

Comment: MichaelCleverly, first - this worked well, but I need to use an exist file and not to download it, only to get it on ajax request. (and it should be XML...)

Comment: I added a small edit. That should be added to your original solution

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis or MichaelCleverly, Can some one explain me  how to use ResponseBody in spring, I am very new to spring...

Comment: That information is readily available in the Spring Documentation, and can be learned fairly more quickly than from these comment threads, respectfully :)

Comment: _That should be added to your original solution_, means on my question? and only your edit?

Comment: I posted a full example in the bottom of my answer

Comment: If you cannot get it to work, I just edited my first solution, so it works with an existing XML file

Comment: I'm so embarrassed, but I have got an empty file. Do you know why? My file is not empty...

Comment: Maybe you didn't specify the corrrect path to the file.